# How do I return only one contact per organization?

Tags: c#, linq, dynamics-crm-2011

I have to return only the primary contact within an account of a person that is a member, but my query is returning all all members within the organization. I have tried reordering it and using stuff like Single() but with no luck. I need a way to put a where clause that says I only want the Primary Contact with an account.

```
if ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(organization)) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(city)) && state != null)
        {
            var corporatemembers = (from a in crmContext.bpt_membertypeSet
                                    where a.bpt_membertypename == "Member (Individual)" || a.bpt_membertypename == "Courtesy"
                                    || a.bpt_membertypename == "Affiliate" || a.bpt_membertypename == "Member"
                                    select new { a.Id }).ToList();

            foreach (var corporatemember in corporatemembers)
            {
                var directories = (from b in crmContext.AccountSet
                                   join a in crmContext.ContactSet
                                   on b.Id equals a.ParentCustomerId.Id
                                   where a.bpt_MemberTypeId.Id == corporatemember.Id
                                   where a.bpt_memberstatus == (int)bpt_memberstatus.Active
                                   where b.Name.Contains(organization)
                                   where a.Address1_City.Contains(city)
                                   where a.bpt_stateorusterritory.Value == state.Value
                                   select new { b.PrimaryContactId, b.EMailAddress1, a.Address1_City, b.Name, b.WebSiteURL, a.bpt_stateorusterritory }).ToList();

                foreach (var directory in directories.ToList().OrderBy(o => o.Name))
                {
                    var cityState = String.Empty;
                    if (directory.bpt_stateorusterritory != null)
                        cityState = directory.Address1_City + ", " + Utility.GetOptionSetValueLabel(crmContext, new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity(Xrm.Contact.EntityLogicalName), "bpt_stateorusterritory", new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OptionSetValue(directory.bpt_stateorusterritory.Value));
                    else
                        cityState = directory.Address1_City;
                    oMemberList.Add(new Members { FullName = directory.PrimaryContactId, FullNameEmail = directory.EMailAddress1, OrganizationName = directory.Name, OrganizationUrl = directory.WebSiteURL, CityState = cityState });
                }

            }
        }
```

this code returns all if the search categories are all filled. I have 4 clauses for all scenarios. But at the end of the whole thing I have:

```
oMembers.ToList()
```

Thanks

Edit: here is sample data but the output is wrong. There should only be one organization and one contact[image]

Comment: Will be much easier to help if you show some sample data and expected output

Comment: @GiladGreen I put a sample picture up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using the wrong field for the join here. This would return all contacts who are a child of that account - which is probably why you are getting multiple results.

`on b.Id equals a.ParentCustomerId.Id`

The primary contact field on the account is `primarycontactid` so I suggest you update your query to reference that attribute instead.

Comment: I got it to work by doing
 
    on b.PrimaryContactId.Id equals a.Id  thank you for pointing out that I needed primarycontactid